# How do i import gtk module to my application? python

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

```
dialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open..",
                           None,
                           gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                           (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                            gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
dialog.set_default_response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)
```

I want to use the above code for file browsing- but when I give the following import

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')

import gtk
```

I get Error: No module named 'pygtk'

Do I need to give pygtk as a module inside my application folder? Do say with steps. Thank you.

Comment: which OS are you using?PyGTK is included in most Linux distributions (including Debian, Fedora, Ubuntu, Opensuse, Gentoo, Mandrake, Redhat, SUSE...);.Give the version of OS too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**pygtk** is the old and deprecated gtk Python api. **Do not use it** unless you have a legacy application. The correct way nowadays is to use GObject-introspection to use Gtk3 from Python. Which is also really awesome as it makes Python a first-class supported language, with no wrappers necessary.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
dlg = Gtk.FileChooserDialog()
dlg.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this: http://rox.sourceforge.net/desktop/node/245.html

It shows some problems. Good luck on fixing it :).

Edit:

[image: Test PyGTK Installation]

This has lots of info on pip install (windows): [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: My installation has a problem it seems. 
    git clone git://git.gnome.org/pygtk installed with this step.

Comment: sudo pip install PyGTK doing that now.

Comment: I am not able to do pip install, the window stays downloading/unpacking idle state for long.